# Compare two get_plugins() (wordpress) results to show versions differences

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress

I have two arrays, each containing results from the WordPress get_plugins() function. I want to find all matching plugins between the two and show the plugin name and plugin versions.

Site One:

```
#From wordpress site one:
$plugins_site_one = get_plugins();
print_r ($plugins_site_one);

Array
(
    [code-snippets/code-snippets.php] => Array
        (
            [Name] => Code Snippets
            [Version] => 2.14.1
            [Description] => NA
            [Author] => Code Snippets Pro
            [AuthorURI] => https://codesnippets.pro
            [TextDomain] => code-snippets
            [Title] => Code Snippets
        )

    [custom-post-widget/custom-post-widget.php] => Array
        (
            [Name] => Content Blocks (Custom Post Widget)
            [Version] => 3.2.2
            [Description] => NA
            [Author] => Johan van der Wijk
            [AuthorURI] => https://vanderwijk.nl
            [TextDomain] => custom-post-widget
            [Title] => Content Blocks (Custom Post Widget)
        )
)
```

Site Two:

```
#From wordpress site two:
$plugins_site_two = get_plugins();
print_r ($plugins_site_two);

Array
(
    [code-snippets/code-snippets.php] => Array
        (
            [Name] => Code Snippets
            [Version] => 1.9.2
            [Description] => NA
            [Author] => Code Snippets Pro
            [AuthorURI] => https://codesnippets.pro
            [TextDomain] => code-snippets
            [Title] => Code Snippets
        )

    [custom-post-widget/custom-post-widget.php] => Array
        (
            [Name] => Content Blocks (Custom Post Widget)
            [Version] => 3.1.0
            [Description] => NA
            [Author] => Johan van der Wijk
            [AuthorURI] => https://vanderwijk.nl
            [TextDomain] => custom-post-widget
            [Title] => Content Blocks (Custom Post Widget)
        )
    [hello-dolly/hello.php] => Array
        (
            [Name] => Hello Dolly
            [PluginURI] => https://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/hello-dolly/
            [Version] => 1.6
            [Description] => NA
            [Author] => Matt Mullenweg
            [AuthorURI] => http://ma.tt/
            [TextDomain] => 
            [Title] => Hello Dolly
        )
)
```

**This is the part i need some assistance with:**
Then I want to compare the two arrays $plugins_site_one and $plugins_site_two, and get just the plugins that are in both sites and the associated versions. e.g. something like below. Format doesnt matter, just the right data to work with.

| plugin file | name | version | site |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| code-snippets/code-snippets.php | Code Snippets | 2.14.1 | site_one |
| code-snippets/code-snippets.php | Code Snippets | 1.9.2 | site_two |
| custom-post-widget/custom-post-widget.php | Content Blocks (Custom Post Widget) | 3.2.2 | site_one |
| custom-post-widget/custom-post-widget.php | Content Blocks (Custom Post Widget) | 3.1.0 | site_two |

Thanks and much appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried anything? Off the top of my head, I'd grab the keys of the array which appear to be the unique parts. Then [`array_diff`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php) would get you what is missing in one compared to the other, then flop it for the other direction, and then [`array_intersect`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php) for what's the same.

Answer (score 0):

OK i think i sorted it out. I got the intersection of the arrays_key from both arrays, Then used the array_keys to filter my two plugin arrays.

```
$arraykeys = array_intersect(array_keys($plugins_site_two),array_keys($plugins_site_one));



$common_plugins_site_one = array_filter($plugins_site_two,fn ($mykey) => in_array($mykey, $arraykeys),ARRAY_FILTER_USE_KEY);

$common_plugins_site_two = array_filter($plugins_site_one,fn ($mykey) => in_array($mykey, $arraykeys),ARRAY_FILTER_USE_KEY);
```

Then i did an array_diff between the two arrays (serialised version of the arrays to overcome using array_diff on multidimensional arrays) to get exact differences.

Thanks